# What does the exclamation mark mean in the end of an A64 instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm, stack, arm64, addressing-mode

The [documentation for LDP and STP](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch05s01s02.html) gives an example instruction with an exclamation mark in the end:

```
LDP X8, X2, [X0, #0x10]!
```

Also the [documentation about porting A32 PUSH/POP](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch08s02s01.html) instructions into A64 gives the following examples:

```
PUSH {r0-r1} ---> STP X0, X1, [SP, #-16]!
POP {r0-r1}  ---> LDP X0, X1, [SP], #16
```

Neither of the pages explains what the exclamation mark in the end of the instructions means. What does it?

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation on addressing modes (the ! denotes that not only is the offset added to `sp` but also is the result written back to `sp` if I recall correctly).

Comment: It means exactly the same thing it has meant in ARM pre-indexed addressing modes for the last 3 decades, and that every instruction set reference covers, _including_ the appropriate section of the very document you linked... (hint: 6.3.4)

Comment: @Notlikethat not everyone has been in this game for 3 decades. Why the shade? Something like this is not easy to search for in the arm architecture documentation.

Answer (score 16):

The `!` means "Register write-back": the base register is used to calculate the address of the transfer, and **is updated**.

In your example:

```
LDP X8, X2, [X0, #0x10]!
```

`X0` modified so that after the operation:

```
X0 = X0 + 0x10
```

If you do not put the `!`, `X0` is not modified by the operation.

On the second example concerning PUSH/POP, the difference is when the increment is done:

`STP X0, X1, [SP, #-16]!` stores at address `SP-16`, and `SP` is decremented in the same way

`LDP X0, X1, [SP], #16` loads from address `SP`, and after the transfer is performed, stores `SP+16` to `SP`.

Comment: This documentation says a different thing: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch05s01s03.html . With `!` the target register is incremented before the operation, without `!` - after.

Comment: The link does not seem correct. But anyway I think you are comparing the 2 write-back forms: `LDR x1, [x0, #imm]!` or `LDR x1, [x0], #imm`. The first form loads at `x0+#imm` (Increment before), the second loads at `x0`.

Comment: This link should be correct: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/CJAIFJII.html

Comment: Thanks. This is similar to what I described: `LDR x1, [x0, #imm]!` does the access at `x0+#imm`, and updates the register to this value. The fact that the register is updated before or after is just a way of describing it.

Comment: "If you do not put the !, X0 is not modified by the operation.", "LDP X0, X1, [SP], #16 loads from address SP, and after the transfer is performed, stores SP+16 to SP." - don't these contradict? As I understand, the register is always updated, just `!` indicates whether before or after.

Comment: The `!` only has a meaning for the form like: `LDR X0, [XP, #16]`, which is called pre-increment. Depending on `!`, the base register is updated or not. For the other form, called post-increment: `LDR X0, [SP], #16`, write-back always occurs (ie base is updated), and `!` is not permitted.